# How to update the tomcat-verstion 7.0.28 to 7.0.67?

Tags: web-server, update, raspbian

i´ve installed a tomcat7 via apt-get install. The current versions 7.0.28 makes some trouble with my servlet, so google says i have to update at least to version 7.0.65 - but i can not find any guide (for raspberry) how to update it manually. I´m new with linux/raspi - could you provide a step by step guide please? Thank you so much!!

Output from `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="raspbian.org/";
SUPPORT_URL="raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"; BUG_REPORT_URL="raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs";
```

Comment: A quick check of the packages on the parent of the Raspian (effectively the "default" Rasberry Pi) distribution, [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tomcat7&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) suggests that not even the "Sid" (permanently unstable, i.e. "bleeding edge") version there is at 7.0.67 at the time of writing (actually is 7.0.64-1) - the "Jessie" version being (.,.56) and the "Wheezy" version is the (...28) one.  Can you tell us the output from typing `cat /etc/os-release`.

Comment: This will indicate whether you are using the "Wheezy"(oldstable) i.e. Raspbian version 6.x or the current, recommended, "Jessie"(stable) version 7.x .  As the Raspian packages tend to follow the Debian parent we can give you advice on how to upgrade from Wheezy to Jessie which won't get you all the way to 7.0.67 but if there is a specific problem with 7.0.28 it may still help you.

Comment: Yes - you have the older distribution - so I guess it isn't a brand new Christmas present! Do you know, or even care about the difference between sysV `init` and `systemd` - probably not - but by default you will be switched to the new `systemd` as the first process during the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` process...!

Comment: In theory you can/should delete that aborted answer - however given that you are likely on the path to finding the answer anyway - you can instead edit it, explaining how a *distribution* upgrade gave you a later tomcat7 version and that that fixed your problem - or so we hope!

Comment: Don't worry about systemd - I have a personal negative view on it but I am very much in a minority and don't want to let my prejudices get in the way...! 8-)

Comment: Choosing the Jessie version - yes - but I had no idea if there is anything you've already got on the SDcard that you want to keep - a fresh install of NOOBS will wipe everything - update/upgrade/dist-upgrades will leave your /home/pi or other user's stuff alone.  This is getting to be a lot of comments pretty soon we will be invited to continue in a chat - so lets do that anyhow - go to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery)

Comment: You *will* need to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as well to jump from Wheezy to Jessie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ SlySven

The updrade from "Wheezy" to "Jessie" worked for me.
Now i got tomcat v 7.0.56 and this works for me to run my webapp / servlet.
It solved errors (in catalina.out) e.g.

Unable to process Jar entry [jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/NativeArray.class] from Jar [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15

Unable to process Jar entry [jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/NativeInt8Array$Constructor.class] from Jar [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15

To upgrade my os i´ve followed this guide (german)

https://www.datenreise.de/raspberry-pi-raspbian-linux-wheezy-jessie-upgrade/